# using integers to set value on datepicker android

Tags: android, datepicker

Can we use integer values like

```
int month = 12;
int year = 2013;
int day = 03;
```

to set values on a date picker ?

for e.g.: 
On using `Bundle args` to `args.putInt("year", calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));` to set the year for the date picker can't we use `args.putInt("year", year);` instead (Even though I already did get an error)?

I am asking this because I need to fetch a string data like

```
String date = "12/03/2013"
```

indicating the date for a project and display it onto the datePicker.

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

you should use init instead:

init(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth, DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener onDateChangedListener)

```
mDatePicker.init(2013,12,3,null);
```

Comment: i only get an `instantiate()` method on call.

Comment: make sure you have that on the top import android.widget.DatePicker

Comment: whose instance is mDatePicker  ?

Comment: DatePicker mDatePicker=new DatePicker(this); mDatePicker.init(...);

Comment: will datepickerfragment do ?

Comment: No, datepicker is a widget, datapickerfragment doesn't exist.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36275/discussion-between-xenione-and-user2247689)